# Rearrange date from yymmdd to mmddyy in SQL

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Here is my code currently. `Job_detal.Date_sequence` is formatted yy/mm/dd and I need it to be mmddyy so Crystal Reports can see the date properly.

```
SELECT 
    JOB_DETAIL.MACHINE
    , JOB_DETAIL.JOB
    , JOB_DETAIL.SUFFIX
    , JOB_DETAIL.SEQ
    , JOB_DETAIL.AMOUNT_LABOR
    , JOB_DETAIL.AMT_OVERHEAD
    , JOB_DETAIL.HOURS_WORKED
    , JOB_DETAIL.DATE_SEQUENCE
 FROM   [TEST].[dbo].[JOB_DETAIL] 
 WHERE  ((JOB_DETAIL.SUFFIX LIKE 'R01' 
    OR JOB_DETAIL.SUFFIX LIKE 'R02' 
    OR JOB_DETAIL.SUFFIX LIKE 'R03' 
    OR JOB_DETAIL.SUFFIX LIKE 'RO1') 
    OR (JOB_DETAIL.SEQ LIKE '5_____' 
    OR JOB_DETAIL.SEQ LIKE '998___')) 
    --AND JOB_DETAIL."DATE_SEQUENCE"='160224'
    ORDER BY JOB_DETAIL.MACHINE
```

Comment: Just use string manipulation to put it in the right format.

Comment: Why not just store [dates using a `DATE/DATETIME` datatype](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) and save yourself some headaches?

Comment: Gordon, im not too familiar with this string manipulation. Something like this? SELECT SUBSTRING(DATE_SEQUENCE,3,4) + SUBSTRING(JOB_DETAIL.DATE_SEQUENCE,1,2)

Comment: You can do it crystal reports there are loads of functions try manipulating in reports itself rather than query

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Thank you all!

```
 SELECT 
    JOB_DETAIL.MACHINE
    , JOB_DETAIL.JOB
    , JOB_DETAIL.SUFFIX
    , JOB_DETAIL.SEQ
    , JOB_DETAIL.AMOUNT_LABOR
    , JOB_DETAIL.AMT_OVERHEAD
    , JOB_DETAIL.HOURS_WORKED
    --, JOB_DETAIL.DATE_SEQUENCE
    , SUBSTRING(JOB_DETAIL.DATE_SEQUENCE,3,4) + SUBSTRING(JOB_DETAIL.DATE_SEQUENCE,1,2) AS DATE2
 FROM   [TEST].[dbo].[JOB_DETAIL] 
 WHERE  ((JOB_DETAIL.SUFFIX LIKE 'R01' 
    OR JOB_DETAIL.SUFFIX LIKE 'R02' 
    OR JOB_DETAIL.SUFFIX LIKE 'R03' 
    OR JOB_DETAIL.SUFFIX LIKE 'RO1') 
    OR (JOB_DETAIL.SEQ LIKE '5_____' 
    OR JOB_DETAIL.SEQ LIKE '998___')) 
        --AND JOB_DETAIL."DATE_SEQUENCE"='160224'
    ORDER BY JOB_DETAIL.MACHINE
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done in a formula (or custom function):

```
datevalue({Job_detal.Date_sequence}[7 to 8] + "/" + {Job_detal.Date_sequence}[4 to 5] +"/" + {Job_detal.Date_sequence}[1 to 2])
```